# Is there a Meta-site for Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, questions, stack-exchange, meta

There is a meta-site for every Stack Exchange site but is there a general Stack Exchange meta-site where we can talk about the Stack Exchange model?

Answer (score 19):

Here. Meta Stack Overflow, the "capital" for the meta sites, [serves as the meta for the following](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq):

- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)
- Stack Exchange
- [Stack Overflow Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com)
- [Stack Apps](http://stackapps.com)