# Is there a meta for stack exchange?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, meta

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a Meta-site for Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66126/is-there-a-meta-site-for-stack-exchange)

If I want to ask a question about the stack exchange network, where do I ask it, because I am redirected to the meta stackoverflow. Is MSO going to be a master meta of somesort?

Comment: You just found it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Meta Stack Overflow is considered the "national capital" of Meta sites. Any questions pertaining to the Stack Exchange network at large should be asked here. The difference between Meta.SO and the per-site meta sites is explained in "[New Per-Site Metas](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/new-per-site-metas/)" on the Stack Overflow blog.

> For now we are leaving meta.stackoverflow.com grandfathered in, as-is, with no changes; it’s still a standalone community with a standalone reputation system. We think Stack Overflow is large enough to justify this, and it just so happens that Stack Overflow is also the name of the company, too. **Meta Stack Overflow will serve as the “National Capital” where we process feedback not just for Stack Overflow but for the core engine itself** — while the smaller meta sites are akin to regional or state capitals.